# C# LINQ filtering with nested if statements

Tags: c#, silverlight, linq-to-entities

I have a learning project where a data grid is filtered by 3 controls (a checkbox and 2 dropdowns)

I'm about to wrap up and move on to another project as it works well but I don't like the complexity of nesting IF statements to capture all the possible combinations of the 3 filters and was wondering if there is a better way. For example: Something that would allow for more filters to be added easily rather than walking through all the nests and adding another level of madness.

```
private void BuildQuery()
    {

        EntityQuery<MASTER_DOCKS> query = QDocksContext.GetMASTER_DOCKSQuery();


        if (Tonnage.IsChecked.HasValue && Tonnage.IsChecked.Value)
        {

            if (null != FilterWaterWay.SelectedValue)
            {

                string WaterwaytoFilterBy = FilterWaterWay.SelectedValue.ToString();

                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(WaterwaytoFilterBy) && WaterwaytoFilterBy != "[Select WaterWay]")
                {

                    if (null != FilterState.SelectedValue)
                    {

                        string StateToFilterBy = FilterState.SelectedValue.ToString();

                        if (null != FilterState.SelectedValue && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(StateToFilterBy) && StateToFilterBy != "[Select State]")
                        {

                            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(StateToFilterBy) && StateToFilterBy != "[Select State]")
                            {

                                query = query.Where(s => s.WTWY_NAME == WaterwaytoFilterBy && s.STATE == StateToFilterBy && (s.Tons != "0" && s.Tons != "")).OrderBy(s => s.WTWY_NAME);


                                MyQuery.Text = "Tonnage, WW and State";

                            }
                        }

                        if (StateToFilterBy == "[Select State]") //waterway but no state
                        {


                            query = query.Where(s => s.WTWY_NAME == WaterwaytoFilterBy && (s.Tons != "0" && s.Tons != "")).OrderBy(s => s.WTWY_NAME);

                            MyQuery.Text = "Tonnage, WW No State";
                        }
                    }
                }

                else 
                {
                    if (null != FilterState.SelectedValue)
                    {

                        string StateToFilterBy = FilterState.SelectedValue.ToString();

                        if (null != FilterState.SelectedValue && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(StateToFilterBy) && StateToFilterBy != "[Select State]")
                        {

                            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(StateToFilterBy) && StateToFilterBy != "[Select State]")
                            {
                                query = query.Where(s => s.STATE == StateToFilterBy && (s.Tons != "0" && s.Tons != "")).OrderBy(s => s.WTWY_NAME);
                                MyQuery.Text = "Tonnage State No WW";
                            }

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            query = query.Where(s => (s.Tons != "0" && s.Tons != ""));
                            MyQuery.Text = "Tonnage No State No WW";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        else //no tonnage
        {

            if (null != FilterWaterWay.SelectedValue)
            {

                string WaterwaytoFilterBy = FilterWaterWay.SelectedValue.ToString();

                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(WaterwaytoFilterBy) && WaterwaytoFilterBy != "[Select WaterWay]")
                {

                    if (null != FilterState.SelectedValue)
                    {

                        string StateToFilterBy = FilterState.SelectedValue.ToString();

                        if (null != FilterState.SelectedValue && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(StateToFilterBy) && StateToFilterBy != "[Select State]")
                        {

                            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(StateToFilterBy) && StateToFilterBy != "[Select State]")
                            {

                                query = query.Where(s => s.WTWY_NAME == WaterwaytoFilterBy && s.STATE == StateToFilterBy).OrderBy(s => s.WTWY_NAME);

                                MyQuery.Text = "No Tonnage, WW and State";

                            }
                        }

                        if (StateToFilterBy == "[Select State]") //waterway but no state
                        {

                            query = query.Where(s => s.WTWY_NAME == WaterwaytoFilterBy).OrderBy(s => s.WTWY_NAME);

                            MyQuery.Text = "No Tonnage, WW No State";
                        }
                    }
                }

                else                     
                {

                    if (null != FilterState.SelectedValue)
                    {

                        string StateToFilterBy = FilterState.SelectedValue.ToString();

                        if (null != FilterState.SelectedValue && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(StateToFilterBy) && StateToFilterBy != "[Select State]")
                        {

                            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(StateToFilterBy) && StateToFilterBy != "[Select State]")
                            {
                                query = query.Where(s => s.STATE == StateToFilterBy).OrderBy(s => s.WTWY_NAME);
                                MyQuery.Text = "No Tonnage State No WW";
                            }

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            LoadAllData();
                            MyQuery.Text = "No Tonnage No State No WW";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        LoadOperation<MASTER_DOCKS> loadOp = this.QDocksContext.Load(query);
        DocksGrid.ItemsSource = loadOp.Entities;
    }
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: I gotta agree...as it's functional it probably does belong on codereview.  but for your own good, you could probably check a bunch of those conditions in one or two if statements instead of that nest of embedded if statements.  For example, your first check should be like so...  if ((Tonnage.IsChecked.HasValue && Tonnage.IsChecked.Value) && FilterWaterWay.SelectedValue != null)
        {  combine the first two things together as one check, and add the second check into the same block of code, then proceed with what you were doing, etc...

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on codereview. Apparently new on more than one level :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than trying to build a single `.Where(...)` call as you're doing, just chain `.Where(...)` calls based on the control settings:

```
if (Tonnage.IsChecked.HasValue && Tonnage.IsChecked.Value)
{
    query = query.Where(s => s.Tons != "0" && s.Tons != "")
}

if (null != FilterWaterWay.SelectedValue)
{
    string WaterwaytoFilterBy = FilterWaterWay.SelectedValue.ToString();

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(WaterwaytoFilterBy) && WaterwaytoFilterBy != "[Select WaterWay]")
    {
         query = query.Where(s => s.WTWY_NAME == WaterwaytoFilterBy);
    }
}

if (null != FilterState.SelectedValue)
{
    string StateToFilterBy = FilterState.SelectedValue.ToString();

    if (null != FilterState.SelectedValue && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(StateToFilterBy) && StateToFilterBy != "[Select State]")
    {
         query = query.Where(s => s.STATE == StateToFilterBy);
    }
}
```

The result, in the case where the check box is checked, and the other two controls have valid values, is the same as:

```
query = query.Where(s => s.Tons != "0" && s.Tons != "")
             .Where(s => s.WTWY_NAME == WaterwaytoFilterBy)
             .Where(s => s.STATE == StateToFilterBy)
```

Comment: Much better. Thank you.